# make flexslider change slide on hovering on thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a flexslider thumnial like this ;
[image]

I want the slide to change when the user hover on thumbnails .How can I do so ?

This is the jquery code I'm using to create the slider:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: "thumbnails",
        start: function (){
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call thumbnail `img` tag's click event inside the hover event handler using JQuery like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: "thumbnails",
    start: function (){
    }
  });

  $(".flex-control-thumbs li img").hover(function(){
    $(this).click();
  });
});
```

**[Working Sample On Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsh85/CPpBD/567/)**

hope that helps.